# Use onChange in Material UI tabs handleChange function in React component

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui

Currently I have a certain navigation setup like this:

```
      <div>
        {letters?.map((letter) => {
          return (
            <button
              type="button"
              key={item.value}
              data-active={value === item.value}
              onClick={() => {
                if (onChange) {
                  onChange(item.value);
                }
              }}
            >
              {item.label}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

I want to change it, to use [Material UI tabs](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/).

I have the following:

```
const MyComponent = ({ firstLetters }: Props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = (_event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: string) => {
    console.warn(newValue);
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
        <Tabs css={styles.tabsRoot} value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
          {firstLetters?.map((item) => {
            return (
              <Tab
                key={item.value}
                label={item.label}
                disableRipple
              />
            );
          })}
        </Tabs>
  )
};
```

How do I use `onChange` like my previous `onClick` function callback into the `handleChange` function?

Comment: Can you show some more code? are you importing the component correctly? are you importing the bootstrap css file correctly?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MUI docs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/), you should have `value` and `onChange` props in the `Tabs` component. So, you should remove the `onClick` prop from the `Tab` components, and add the aforementioned `Tabs` props like so:

```
<Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
  {letters?.map((item) => {
    return (
      <Tab
        key={item.value}
        label={item.label}
        disableRipple
        value={item.value}
      />
    );
  })}
</Tabs>
```

Comment: ok so now I have to figure out how to create the `handleChange` function so it has same behaviour as my previous `onClick` callback. Do you have any idea how to set this up using 'useState'?